# Singe Page Application External Configurations (Not On NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, apache, angularjs, backbone.js, ember.js

I'm looking for either a reference or an answer to what I think is a very common problem that people who are current implementing JavaScript MVC frameworks (such as Angular, Ember or Backbone) would come across.

I am looking for a way or common pattern to externalize application properties that are accessible in the JS realm. Something that would allow the javascript to load server side properties such as endpoints, salts, etc. that are external to the application root. The issue that I'm coming across is that browsers do not typically have access to the file systems because it is a security concerns.

Therefore, what is the recommended approach for loading properties that are configurable outside of a deployable artifact if such a thing exists?

If not, what is currently being used or is in practice that is considered the recommended approach for this types of problem?

I am looking for a cross compatible answer (Google Chrome is awesome, I agree).

Comment: You want to provide your application config options before it bootstraps, right? Say, a user opens you app and before app actually starts it fetches from server (or somewhere else) some starting options such as routes.

Comment: You got it, that's what I've been trying to wrestle with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data Driven Local Storage Pattern**

Just came up with that!!

The idea is to load the configuration properties based on a naming over convention configuration where all properties are derived from the targeted hostname. That is, the hostname will derive a trusted endpoint and that endpoint will load the corresponding properties to the application. These application properties will contain information that is relative at runtime. The runtime information will be supplied to the integration parts which then communicate via property iteration on the bootstrapping start up.

To keep it simple, we'll just use two properties here:

**This implementation is Ember JS specific but the general idea should be portable**

I am currently narrowing the scope of this question to a specific technological perspective, that is Ember JS with the following remedy that is working properly for me and hope it will help any of you out there dealing with the same issue.

**Ember.Application.initializer implementation in start up**

```
initialize: function (container, application) { 
      var origin = window.location.origin;
      var host = window.location.hostname;
      var port = window.location.port;
      var configurationEndPoint = '';


      //local mode
     if(host === 'localhost'){

        //standalone using api stub on NODEJS
        if(port === '8000'){
            configurationEndPoint = '/api/local';
        }//standalone UI app integrating with back end application on same machine, different port
        else{
          configurationEndPoint = '/services/env';
        }
      origin += configurationEndPoint;
   }else{
      throw Error('Unsupported Environment!!');
   }

   //load the configuration from a trusted resource and store it in local storage on start up
   $.get(origin,
    function( data ) {
         //load all configurations as key value pairs and store in localStorage for access. 
         configuration = data.configuration;
         for(var config in configuration){
             debugger;
             var objectProperty = localStorage + '.' + config.toString()
             objectProperty = configuration[config];
         }       
   }
);
```

}

**Configurable Adapter**

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
host:       localStorage.host,
namespace:  localStorage.namespace
```

});

Answer (score 0):

No later than yesterday morning i was tackling the same issue.

Basically, you have two options:

1. Use localStorage/indexedDB or any other client-side persistent storage. (But you have to put config there somehow).
2. Render your main template (the one that gets rendered always) with a hidden  where you put config JSON.

Then in your app init code you get this config and use it. Plain and simple in theory, but lets get down to nasty practice (for second option).

First, client should get config before application loads. It is not easy sometimes. e.g. user should be logged in to see config. In my case i check if i can provide config on the first request, and if not redirect user to login page. This leads us to second limitation. Once you are ready to provide config, you have to reboot app completely so that configuration code run again (at least in Angular it is necessary, as you cannot access providers after the app bootstraps).

Another constraint, the second option is useless if you use static html and cannot change it somehow on server before sending to the client.

May be a better option would be to combine both variants. This should solve some problems for returning users, but first interaction will not be very pleasant anyway. I have not tried this yet.

Comment: Hey Eugene, 

Thanks for taking a look into this. I appreciate any help. I am going to update this question with my approach which is somewhat derived from your input here.